# Eclipse 4.2 on Mountain Lion: gatekeeper rejects as unidentified developer?

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

Just updated the mountain lion, and download the latest Eclipse 4.2 to upgrade the old one. However when opening the application, it shows that it is from an unidentified developer and the gatekeeper refuses to open it.

I know that there is an option to change the security and privacy option to allow it, however I want to know whether there is a way to just add eclipse into the list. Any hint on this?

More information: before updating I have the Eclipse 3.7.2 on machine, and after updating it works smoothly (I think I have added it into the allow list). So is there a way to do this to Eclipse 4.2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Right-click the Eclipse application and choose open.  This should make OS X trust it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. disable Gatekeeper ("Allow applications downloaded from: Anywhere")
2. run Eclipse once
3. reset Gatekeeper to a more strict level ("Mac Store and identified developers".)

Doing this has allowed me to start Davmail, also a Java app, after Mountain Lion initially claimed the binary was corrupt ("App is damaged and can’t be opened" error message) even when back on the stricter level.

Another option, as mentioned in John Siracusa's [excellent review](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2012/07/os-x-10-8/15/#game-of-gates), is to do the following from the Terminal:

```
% xattr -d com.apple.quarantine /path/to/Eclipse.app
```

I have not (yet) personally tested this but John's a solid source.

Comment: Yes, the command works ;)

Comment: Alternate unpacking tools may also work. E.g. when extracting the archive StuffIt expander, Eclipse.app can be run without any problems...

Answer (score 7):

Actually, just right-click on any app that Gatekeeper complains about and select "Open". You'll get a warning, but one of the buttons is "open". After you select "open" in the dialog box, you'll never see the warning for that application again.

This is explained as exempting the specific application in Apple's Gatekeeper FAQ:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202491

Answer (score 5):

**No**, there's no specific editable "list" for Gatekeeper. Apps that are already present on your system are by default added to the Gatekeeper "whitelist", which is why it runs without incident after you updated to Mountain Lion.

The only options you have are to change your security preferences to allow all apps, or to right/Control-click on the newly downloaded app and select "Open". This will allow you to bypass Gatekeeper for that app now and always.

Comment: There is such a list: /var/db/SystemPolicy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is such a list:

from `man spctl`

```
/var/db/SystemPolicy.
```

Use the spctl tool to add and remove items from the policy.